# AngularJS - object losing values on copy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object, deep-copy

So, I have this huge object (it's a restaurant menu) and I want to save only the fields I change on it. I found that the best way to do that is to have an "original" and compare it to the modified version of the object.
The problem is that whathever way I use to deep copy makes me lose some info.
I tried

```
this.menu = menu;    
this.oldMenu = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.menu));
```

and

```
this.menu = menu;
this.oldMenu = angular.copy(this.menu);
```

and they both return me different arrays (all the boolean variables and the final chunk of the menu are missing in the copy).
Then, I tried making two variables in the php file, and use them independently, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  menu         = <?= ($menu) ? json_encode($menu) : 'false' ; ?>;
  menuCopy     = <?= ($menu) ? json_encode($menu) : 'false' ; ?>;
</script>
```

and then

```
this.menu = menu;
this.menuCopy = menuCopy;
```

but I get the exact same issue: the copy misses the same variables. And the weird thing about it is that if I reverse the order like this:

```
this.menuCopy = menu;
this.menu = menuCopy;
```

it still is `this.menuCopy` that misses the variables.

What I am not seeing? I read somewhere that JSON simply ignores the booleans when copying, is that true? Does Angular do the same? If that's the case, how can do this duplication?

EDIT:
I edited out a piece of the menu, but basically, I get one of them like this:

```
{"id":2442,"categories":[{"id":13364,"itens":[{"id":136056},
{"id":136057,"daily_promo":null}],
"daily_promo":null}],"daily_promo":null}
```

and the other one like this:

```
{"id":2442,"categories":[{"id":13364,"itens":[{"id":136056,"update_price":false},
{"id":136057,"daily_promo":null,"update_price":false}],
"daily_promo":null,"itens_length":[{"id":136056,"name":"teste 1","category_id":13364,"daily_promo":null,"update_price":false},{"id":136057,"name":"teste 2","category_id":13364,"daily_promo":null,"update_price":false}]}],"daily_promo":null}
```

the code doesn't have much more to it, it's pretty much like:

```
angular.module('menu', [])
    .controller('MenuController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', function($rootScope, $scope, $http){

        this.restaurant                 = (restaurant) ? restaurant : false ;
        this.oldRestaurant = angular.copy(this.restaurant); 
}
```

and then the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller = "CulinaryController as CulinaryController">
        ORIGINAL MENU <br/>
        {{MenuController.oldRestaurant.menu}}
        <br/><br/><br/>
        CHANGED MENU <br/>
        {{MenuController.restaurant.menu}}
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      restaurant = <?= ($restaurant) ? json_encode($restaurant) : 'false' ; ?>;
    </script>
```

the `$restaurant` comes from my Controller (I am using Cakephp).

Comment: Without seeing your code, A pluker with nested items in the JSON seems to works: https://plnkr.co/edit/qgvkj33I8t0hG3XmOwv7

Comment: angular.copy has always worked for me for objects of any size. what exactly is being lost?

Comment: @Ero I edited the question with answers to both questions. Now you can see the code and the Object.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if this is an angularjs problem. You said you are using cakePHP maybe something with your json_encode is not working? I don't know cakePHP so won't be much help there